# How to collect dynamic client-side data and pass it to server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, client-side

I need some direction on how to procede in this scenario. Using and Asp.Net page with JQuery, user generates dynamic elements representing data of his process' tasks:
-Basically, at the left, right and bottom of the page, there are several accordion with a sort of draggable items
-In the middle of the page, there is a 'PLUS' button
-Where user hits '+', a new 'CARD' is dynamically generated in the middle of the page. This card is a main div, with some droppable divs inside it
-This card represents the user task, and the inner divs are the properties of the current task
-The user drags the options from the lateral accordions and drops them on the droppable areas/div of the card/main div.
-Done! The 'task characterization' of the task is done.
-The process is repeated, adding more cards as required.

All this operation is client-side: until this moment, there is no needed to invoke server operations.
Until now, and this is where my question is laid: when the user is done, he hits a 'SAVE' button.
How can I go from a dynamic set of HTML controls on the client to, lets say, a IEnumerable of a custom class type containing the user data to proceed with data operations?

These are some of my ideas:

Idea #1:
 1. On Page_Load, instantiate a list of 'TaskData'
 2. When user hits Save, using Jquery, select all elements of the card class
 3. Loop through all card
 4. Select and loop all elements of the card, reading data of the droppable areas
 5. Pass data to server (using webservice or page_methods)

Idea #2:

1. On Page_Load, instantiate a list of 'TaskData'
2. At each 'drop' event, call a specific page_method, eg: setPropertyX(string value), setPropertyY(string value), and so on, avoiding callbacks. This way, on the Save method, I would have the objects to be populated progressively.

Idea #3:

1. At each 'drop' event, store values on array variables
2. ...

Idea #4:

1. Use browser' localstorage/sessionstorage, or browser DB (new area to me)

So, as you can see, I'm pretty stuck at this. Suggestions are welcome :-)

Comment: Simplest: Before hitting _Save_ button, just dump the data as json into some hidden field. In the code behind deserialize that json data.

Comment: @mshsayem yes, I guess you're talking about my idea #1. Passing the data to server is ok, but how do I collect the data? Isn't there a easier way than looping through tons of HTML elements?